# How can I select an element basing on its dataset and using template strings?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to select a paragraph element with the data-id equal to the variable using template strings but it's only causing an error saying that it is not a valid selector. Here it is how it looks like:

```
document.querySelector(`p.dataset.id="${item.name}"`);
```

How can I do it in another way and why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) (Equals):

```
p[data-id=${item.name}]
```

**Demo:**

```js
var item = {name: 'test'};
var p = document.querySelector(`p[data-id=${item.name}]`);
console.log(p.textContent);
```

```html
<p data-id="test">Test Content</p>
```